# Invalid endian flag value encountered on Spring Boot Spatial Query on PostGis

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, gis, postgis

I'm trying to query all `property`'s in a circular area defined by a point.
I implemented a basic CRUDRepository in Spring Boot with the Following function, which I hoped to use to search properties via an area from a point.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM property p WHERE ST_DWithin(geography(p.location), geography(:center), :radius)", nativeQuery = true)
 List<Property> searchPropertyByArea(@Param("center") Point center,
                                    @Param("radius") Integer radius);
```

But I keep getting: ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered.

The entity object:

```
public class Property {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
 @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
 @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false, nullable = false, unique  = true)
 private UUID id;

 @Column(name = "location", nullable = true, columnDefinition = "geometry(POINT,4326)")
 @JsonSerialize(using = PointSerializer.class)
 @JsonDeserialize(using = PointDeserializer.class)
 private Point location;
}
```

The libraries I'm using are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
   <version>5.4.27.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

with my `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means that the first byte of a geometry given in WKB or EWKB format is neither 0 (big endian) nor 1 (little endian):

```
SELECT geometry('0101000000000000000000F03F0000000000000040');

                  geometry                  
--------------------------------------------
 0101000000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
(1 row)

SELECT geometry('0401000000000000000000F03F0000000000000040');
ERROR:  Invalid endian flag value encountered.
LINE 1: SELECT geometry('0401000000000000000000F03F0000000000000040'...
                        ^
```

So either `p.location` or `:center` start with a number, but not with `00` or `01`.

Comment: Thank you, it was the `center` value that was not the correct endian.